# Mock Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new in Chef unit/rspec test?

Tags: windows, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I found Fauxhai works for mocking the information in "node" but it doesn't mock Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new.

Is there anyway to mock this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard RSpec applies so `allow(Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version).to receive(:new).and_return(double('fake version'))` or similar.

Comment: I've tried this solution, although I don't know if I am doing this correctly. For more details, please see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112870/mock-chefreservednameswin32version-new-in-chef-unit-rspec-test-continued "Mock Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new in Chef unit/rspec test? [continued]"). Thanks!