# Mock Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new in Chef unit/rspec test? [continued]

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

Assuming, I have the following recipe:

**install_iis:**

```
require 'chef/win32/version'
windows_version = Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new

node.set['iis']['components'] = [
  'IIS-HttpErrors',
  'IIS-HttpRedirect',
  'IIS-HttpLogging',
  'IIS-LoggingLibraries',
  'IIS-RequestMonitor',
  'WAS-WindowsActivationService',
  'WAS-ProcessModel',
  'IIS-StaticContent',
  'IIS-DefaultDocument',
  'IIS-DirectoryBrowsing'
]

include_recipe 'iis::default'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_aspnet'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_auth_basic'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_auth_windows'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_compress_static'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_security'
include_recipe 'iis::mod_management'

if windows_version.windows_server_2012_r2?
  include_recipe 'iis::mod_aspnet45'
  include_recipe 'iis::mod_tracing'
  include_recipe 'iis::mod_application_initialization'
end
```

I want to be able to test, using chefspec, if the `include_recipe` methods are running (everything in the `if` block).

---

**After reading:**

> Standard RSpec applies so `allow(Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version).to receive(:new).and_return(double('fake version'))` or similar.
>
> **Source:** [Mock Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new in Chef unit/rspec test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931987/mock-chefreservednameswin32version-new-in-chef-unit-rspec-test/34936359#34936359)

I've attempted to modified my `install_iis_spec` to mock the `Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version`. My spec file now looks like the following:

**install_iis_spec:**

```
recipes_2012 = [
  'iis::mod_aspnet45',
  'iis::mod_tracing',
  'iis::mod_application_initialization'
]

context 'when on "Windows Server 2012 R2"' do
  before do
    allow(Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version).to receive(:new).and_return(double('6.3'))
  end

  let(:chef_run) do
    runner = ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2')
    runner.converge(described_recipe)
  end

  should_include_recipe(recipes_2012)

  it 'converges successfully' do
    expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
  end
end
```

**Note<sub>1</sub>:** Assume that the `should_include_recipe` method works as intended.

**Note<sub>2</sub>:** After seeing `double('fake version')`, I assume I should be putting the value [`'6.3'`](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/271d3e4f91e3d158c9112512ac75d0ca51fc928d/lib/chef/win32/version.rb#L54).

Although, when I run `chef exec rspec spec/unit/recipes/install_iis_spec.rb` I get the following error:

**Console Error:**

```
my_recipe::install_iis when on "Windows Server 2012 R2" runs the 'iis::mod_aspnet45' recipe
  Failure/Error: runner.converge(described_recipe)
    #<Double "6.3"> received unexpected message :windows_server_2008? with (no args)
 # C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/d20161018-26632-iyzn4f/cookbooks/iis/libraries/helper.rb:44:in `older_than_windows2008r2?'
 # C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\d20161018-26632-iyzn4f\cookbooks\iis\recipes\default.rb:22:in `from_file'
 # C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\d20161018-26632-iyzn4f\cookbooks\my_recipe\recipes\install_iis.rb:23:in `from_file'
 # ./spec/unit/recipes/install_iis_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in should_include_recipe'
```

**Ref:** [cookbooks/iis/libraries/helper.rb:44:in 'older_than_windows2008r2?'](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis/blob/b4b503d0721c3f367410901acd5f28453dadeee9/libraries/helper.rb#L44).

---

What value do I have to put, in `double('fake version')`, in order to target `Windows Server 2012R2`?

Is there a list of supported versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'6.3'` is just a label for the fake version object. You need to tell it how to respond to methods. In this, it's pretty easy: `double('fake version', :windows_server_2008? => false)` (or `true` if you want to pretend to be true). Normally you would do this in a `before` block, like this:

```
before do
  allow(Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version).to receive(:new).and_return(double('fake version', :windows_server_2008? => false))
end
```

You can find more info on how to use RSpec in the RSpec documentation or in any of several thousand tutorials I'm sure are available via Google.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me. Adding `:windows_server_2008? => false` did the trick for that part. Once I did that I get an error for [`windows_vista?`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis/blob/b4b503d0721c3f367410901acd5f28453dadeee9/libraries/helper.rb#L45 "github iis cookbook"), which is the next one in the list. I believe I have to add all these to the `and_return`, although I'm just wondering if there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This is how mocking works, you need to specifically code every method.